# How to mock Callback answer for static methods with PowerMock?

Tags: android, powermock

I need to mock some static methods, that's fine so far and can be done like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DataService.class})
public class PlayersAllViewModelTest {

// mock objects
private PlayersAllContextHandler mContextHandler;
private PlayersAllAdapter mAdapter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    mockStatic(DataService.class);

    //define mocks
    mContextHandler = mock(PlayersAllContextHandler.class);
    mAdapter = mock(PlayersAllAdapter.class);

}

@Test
public void check_init_requests_are_done() throws Exception {

    // create instance of viewmodel
    new PlayersAllViewModel(mContextHandler, mAdapter);

    // check dataservice is requested for method 'getAllPlayers()'
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
    DataService.getAllPlayers(any(DataServiceCallback.class));

}
```

I need to test the behavior for a given response (success() / failure()) answered in a callback. The normal way to do so is like this:

```
    // define mock answer
    doAnswer(new Answer<MyCallback<String>>() {
        @Override
        public MyCallback answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            MyCallback<Player> callback = (MyCallback<Player>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            callback.onFailure(new UnsupportedOperationException());
            return null;
        }
    }).when(>>mocked class instance<<).myTestMethod(any(MyCallback.class));
```

Because is want to call a static method, i can't do it like that so. There's no mocked instance of a class that could fill the gap :(

Does anybody know what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Would it be an option, to well, improve your design and get right of the static stuff in the first place?

Comment: @GhostCat That's not really an option because I want to decouple dependencies. To set a instance of a object as method parameter, that's where I startet and I want to get rid of these hardcoded dependencies.

By the way, I think it's no good implementation pattern to pass a instance of a object as method parameter just to be able to test/mock it's behavior. There must be another option for handling that I guess...!?

Comment: So hard coding a class name is not coupling? And you might not pass that object as parameter, but for example have a field in your class and use dependency injection. Having an interface for the functionality you need to call, and the option to use polymorphism... That is good OOP. Static calls not so much.